MS Teams Bot Cannot Respond on Web Chat
I have created a bot via MS Teams. I registered the bot in MS Bot Framework portal and then created an app that is connected to this bot on Teams.
I am able to chat with my bot and it responds without an issue. However, it does not work when I try to use the web chat option that is provided to test the bot in the Bot Framework portal. It fails when I try to respond with a 'forbidden' error. What could be causing this? This is the Python code I am using to send responses:
credentials = MicrosoftAppCredentials(
    app_id=APP_ID,
    password=APP_PASSWORD
)

connector = ConnectorClient(credentials, base_url=SERVICE_URL)
connector.conversations.send_to_conversation(
    CONVERSATION_ID,
    Activity(
        type=ActivityTypes.message,
        channel_id=CHANNEL_ID,
        recipient=ChannelAccount(
            id=RECIPIENT_ID
        ),
        from_property=ChannelAccount(
            id=FROM_ID,
        ),
        text="HELLO WORLD!"
    )
)

All of these attributes such as the SERVICE_URL and so forth are extracted from the message that is sent by the bot.
How can I refactor this to also reply on the web chat?

Is 'Web Chat' added in channel settings of your Azure Bot? https://i.sstatic.net/26cS8JzM.png

I am not running my bot on Azure. At the moment, I am just running it locally.

Could you refer to this troubleshooting guide for the Bot Framework? This guide provides detailed steps to diagnose and resolve common issues, including authentication problems and configuration errors

WebChat ?? when running locally, does it use DirectLine or run on top of the emulator?
